# nasm: fatal: Unable to open input file

Tags: nasm

I have problems facing assembly on mac. Every time i try to run something it shows an error that unable to open file.

> nasm: fatal: Unable to open input file `h1.asm`

Can anyone tell me an alternate of nasm?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem appears to be with the file you are trying to open, not with the `nasm` application.

Make sure the file exists `h1.asm` exists in the current directory that you are running the command from.

For example, if the file exists on the Desktop then perform this:

```
cd ~/Desktop
nasm -f macho h1.asm
```

or

```
nasm -f macho ~/Desktop/h1.asm
```

Comment: Thanx man. It's located on my desktop and don't know how to specify it's location.

Comment: `cd ~/Desktop` followed by your command; see my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

Check the extension for the file. If you save that file in windows with `h1.asm` but forget to change the save as type from text file to all documents, then it will save the file as `h1.asm.txt` and you will get the same error:

> nasm: fatal: Unable to open input file h1.asm

so change the type to all documents.